# Display a tutorial

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am doing an application with some layouts and when the application start I want to display a tutorial in the kind of the one Google's using.

I didn't find any information about this on internet, only basic tutorials. I really want to display the gesture the user have to use to navigate through the application.

Is there a way to display a tutorial like this ?

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial on displaying tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Library which display the same blue circles as used by Google :

[ShowcaseView Library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Then I just added Gesture icons over the view, from this free icons set :

[Touch Gesture Icons](http://www.mobiletuxedo.com/touch-gesture-icons/)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'd do is to store the shown status of the tutorial in a persistant storage like [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Beyond that, you can use Animations and ImageViews to show the actions you want the user to know about.

You might get some ideas about locating the animations on the screen from another one of my answers regarding help overlays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10978362/1069068).

In short, you dynamically get the location of the element on the screen, and position the help information accordingly. This allows it to work well across different screen sizes as well.