# Android users tips api?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display a “help” overlay over an Android layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757093/display-a-help-overlay-over-an-android-layout)

is there any api that enable us to create user tips/tutorial to users, similar to the tips that appear in Android 4 when used for the first time

Answer (score 0):

you can look at that [example](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/08/overlay-on-android-layout.html) , i think it will give an idea to you